# JavaFx-when fxml inject object field?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to javaFx,and I have found only within the @fxml function and initialize function the @fxml field not be null otherwise the @fxml field will always be null,is it true?
If so,how can i use a @fxml field immediately after i load a fxml(do not use lookup),just like this?(the code follow will throw a null exception)

```
    @FXML Label resultTF;
    ....
    FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setController(this);

    Parent pane = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
    this.resultTF.setText("");
```

All i want to do is to declare a field with id in the fxml,and use it immediately after load the fxml,something like wpf,flex

Comment: sorry,It's a mistake,i edited the code

Comment: Ok,I konw what happen now,the load method i call is a static method.Because it has the same name with the non-static load,so i didn't realize that,so i think java can call static method from a instance is a bad design :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the static [`FXMLLoader.load(URL)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) method.

Since it's a static method, it knows nothing about the instance you are using to invoke it (which is bad practice anyway; your IDE should issue a warning about this). Specifically, it doesn't have a controller set.

You need to invoke an [instance `load()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--), e.g.

```
FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(this);
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));

Parent pane = loader.load();
```

Comment: wow,I didn't realized it was a static method because it have the same name with the object method.

Comment: @BlackCat Yes, it's not a particularly good API design; however as I said your IDE should be flagging this and suggesting you change it to the equivalent `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(...))`.

Comment: no,i use eclipse and it do not show any suggest,maybe idea will suggest me

Comment: @BlackCat I would check your Eclipse settings (either project or workspace). Under "Java Compiler", "Errors/Warnings", in the "Code Style" section you should see "Non-static access to static member". I would set that to "Warning". Then you should see your original code underlined in yellow.

Comment: Thank you,it indeed show a warning after i set that.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the controller in the FXML file. The FXMLLoader will initialize the variables in the controller. In that case there is not problem with your code. It is good practice to separate the controller from the main class.

Comment: There's nothing in the OP that suggests the controller is the same as the main class, though. There are plenty of patterns in which you would load the FXML from the controller, e.g. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components

Comment: How so? You would have to assume that code is in the "main class" (which it really should not be; the main class should only manage the application life cycle). The OP says (s)he is trying to mimic wpf and/or flex, which I think tend to use MVVM-type designs (though I am not an expert in those technologies). In that design you would want to load the view from the controller.